# buildPdfDocument null pointer exception

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, nullpointerexception, pdfview

The code that creates a pdf file works fine when the filestorePath is hardcode.
As soon as I replace the hardcoded filestorePath with a value fetched from a database, I get a NullPointerException when the view is called.
The query returns the correct value, because the logic is used in other places in the code and there it works fine.

Any ideas?

```
public class PDFDeliveryNoteBuilder extends AbstractPdfViewCustom{

Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PDFDeliveryNoteBuilder.class);

@Autowired
private RepositoryJdbcTemplate dbRepository;

private BaseFont bfBold;
private BaseFont bf;
private int pageNumber = 0;

protected void buildPdfDocument(Map<String, Object> model, Document doc,
                    PdfWriter docWriter, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                    throws Exception {

    //String filestorePath = "/xxx/www/xxxxx/tmp/";
    //TODO gives null pointer exception
    SysParam sysParam = dbRepository.findSysParam();
    String sysTmpdir = sysParam.getSysTmpdir();
    String filestorePath = sysTmpdir;
    String downloadfileNm = "DeliveryNote.pdf";
    String filePath = filestorePath+downloadfileNm;
    logger.debug("--> filePath: "+filePath);
    initializeFonts();

    try {
        // get data model which is passed by the Spring container
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<AuditTrailHist> auditTrailHistPublishDeliveredList = (ArrayList<AuditTrailHist>) model.get("auditTrailHistDeliveredList");

        docWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance(doc , new FileOutputStream(filePath));
        doc.addAuthor("xxx");
        doc.addCreationDate();
        doc.addProducer();
        doc.addCreator("xxx");
        doc.addTitle("Delivery Note");
        doc.setPageSize(PageSize.LETTER);
        doc.open();
        PdfContentByte cb = docWriter.getDirectContent();
        boolean beginPage = true;
        int y = 0;
        //get the most recent audit trail history record for header
        Integer size = auditTrailHistPublishDeliveredList.size();
        AuditTrailHist auditTrailHistRecentRec = auditTrailHistPublishDeliveredList.get(size-1);
        //get all the audit trail history records for detail
        for (AuditTrailHist auditTrailHist : auditTrailHistPublishDeliveredList) {
            if(beginPage){
                beginPage = false;
                generateLayout(doc, cb);
                generateHeader(doc, cb,auditTrailHistRecentRec);
                y = 615; 
            }
            generateDetail(doc, cb, auditTrailHist, y);
            y = y - 15;
            if(y < 50){
                printPageNumber(cb);
                doc.newPage();
                beginPage = true;
            }
        }
        printPageNumber(cb);
    }
    catch (DocumentException dex) {
        dex.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        if (doc != null){
            doc.close();
        }
        if (docWriter != null) {
            docWriter.close();
        }
    }
} //end buildPdfDocument
```

Here is the error log:

```
2015-04-22 23:53:41.551 DEBUG   org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils [http-bio-8080-exec-3]  Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
2015-04-22 23:53:41.552 DEBUG   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory    [http-bio-8080-exec-3]  Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'pdfDeliveryNoteView'
2015-04-22 23:53:41.552 DEBUG   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet   [http-bio-8080-exec-3]  Rendering view [com.xxxx.view.PDFDeliveryNoteBuilder: name 'pdfDeliveryNoteView'] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
2015-04-22 23:53:41.679 DEBUG   com.xxx.view.PDFDeliveryNoteBuilder [http-bio-8080-exec-3]  --> before dbRepository
2015-04-22 23:53:41.681 DEBUG   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet   [http-bio-8080-exec-3]  Error rendering view [com.xxxx.view.PDFDeliveryNoteBuilder: name 'pdfDeliveryNoteView'] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.xxxx.view.PDFDeliveryNoteBuilder.buildPdfDocument(PDFDeliveryNoteBuilder.java:48)
    at com.xxxx.view.AbstractPdfViewCustom.renderMergedOutputModel(AbstractPdfViewCustom.java:92)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
```

Below the spring XML configuration.
web.xml

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

<display-name>xxx Web Application</display-name>
<description>xxx Web Application</description> 

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/spring-mvc-dispatcher.xml
        /WEB-INF/spring-jdbc.xml
        /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-mvc-dispatcher.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping> 

<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/jsp/notfound.jsp</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <error-code>403</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/jsp/notauthorized.jsp</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
    <location>/WEB-INF/jsp/error.jsp</location>
</error-page>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/resources/index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

spring-mvc-dispatcher.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"   
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation=" 

http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd

http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd 

http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.xxx" />

<mvc:resources location="/resources/" mapping="/resources/**"/>

<mvc:annotation-driven />

<!-- <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping" /> -->

<bean id="xmlViewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.XmlViewResolver">
   <property name="location"><value>/WEB-INF/spring-mvc-views.xml</value>
   </property><property name="order" value="0" />
</bean>

<bean id="jspViewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" >
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
    <property name="prefix"> <value>/WEB-INF/jsp/</value></property>
    <property name="suffix"> <value>.jsp</value></property>
    <property name="order" value="1" />
</bean>

<bean id="messageSource" 
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="messages" />
</bean>

<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <!-- set to 5 MB
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="5242880"/>
    --> 
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
    <property name="useDefaultSuffixPattern" value="false" />
</bean>

<!-- Validator beans  -->
<bean id="deliveryDataStoreCreateValidator" class="com.xxx.validator.DeliveryDataStoreCreateValidator" />
<bean id="deliveryDataStoreUpdateValidator" class="com.xxx.validator.DeliveryDataStoreUpdateValidator" />
<bean id="deliveryDataStoreAccessUpdateValidator" class="com.xxx.validator.DeliveryDataStoreAccessUpdateValidator" />
<bean id="reportTemplateCreateValidator" class="com.xxx.validator.ReportTemplateCreateValidator" />
<bean id="reportTemplateUpdateValidator" class="com.xxx.validator.ReportTemplateUpdateValidator" />
<bean id="reportTemplateAccessUpdateValidator" class="com.xxx.validator.ReportTemplateAccessUpdateValidator" />
<bean id="dataProfileIdFileValidator" class="com.xxx.validator.DataProfileIdFileValidator" />
<bean id="dataProfileIdValidator" class="com.xxx.validator.DataProfileIdValidator" />
<bean id="dataProfileCreateValidator" class="com.xxx.validator.DataProfileCreateValidator" />
<bean id="dataProfileUpdateValidator" class="com.xxx.validator.DataProfileUpdateValidator" />
<bean id="dataProfileAccessUpdateValidator" class="com.xx.validator.DataProfileAccessUpdateValidator" />
<bean id="userCreateValidator" class="com.xxx.validator.UserCreateValidator" />
<bean id="userUpdateValidator" class="com.xxx.validator.UserUpdateValidator" />
```

spring-mvc-views.xml:

```
<bean id="pdfDeliveryNoteView" class="com.xxx.view.PDFDeliveryNoteBuilder">
```

Comment: Post the null pointer exception trace.

Comment: The NullPointer means: `RepositoryJdbcTemplate` is not correctly "autowired"! (Are both classes in component-scan ?)

Comment: The RepositoryJdbcTemplate is autowired in other places in the code the same way, and works fine. The difference is that I autowire in a view. Need I do additional XML configuration setup to use autowire in a view?

Comment: Post your controller code. You are also aware that you are duplicating all the beans in your `spring-mvc-dispatcher.xml` because tis file is being loaded twice? Your application basically takes more memory then needed because of unnecessary bean instances.